# Is there a possibility to draw several cylinders or tubes in a matlab figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, mplot3d

I have 3-D plot in matlab and it contain several lines. I want to draw cylinder or hollow tubes around those line. Is someone has experience of plotting several cylinder in 3-D plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a possibility. There is a possibility of everything in Matlab!

Lets Google and find: [`cylinder()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cylinder.html)!

Fantastic, Matlab has a function to generate cylinders!

And... That's it. Go plot them wherever you want.

Fun:

```
clear;clc;
cmap = hsv(10);
for ii=1:10
    hold on
   [X,Y,Z]=cylinder(rand(1,1)*0.4);
   h=surf(X+(rand(1,1)-10)*2,Y+(rand(1,1)-10)*2,Z*rand(1,1)*10,'FaceColor',cmap(ii,:));
end
```

[image]

Comment: I have one question, If I want to get tilted cylinder

Comment: @User1551892 mmThats another question. You better ask it again with the new problem. What I would do is to create a rotation matrix with the desired rotation  and then multiplly your et of points by that matrix(this is quite easy to do).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I have several diagonal lines and they are tilted with different angles and even they are not straight. Thats why, I mentioned in my question that I want to plot cylinder or tube along lines.

Comment: @User1551892 It should be not too dificult to get the rotation angle of those lines and create rotation matrixes for the cylindres here. ;)

Comment: Generate the `cylinder` indices, then rotate them to get it diagonal.  Check this file out on the Mathworks File Exchange: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30304-rotatedata